# Starting a fragment from an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My navigation drawer items are fragments. I want to start the settings fragment from the activity but i keep getting the error below:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09005a (example.com.jay:id/content_home) for fragment SettingsFragment{3f879650 #2 id=0x7f09005a}

I cant find what I'm missing

My code to start the fragment:

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    SettingsFragment settings= new SettingsFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_home , settings);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

layout file: activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jay.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have done this in you MainActivity in onCreate block right after super.onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

If you have, where from are you doing the fragment transaction? Because it seems like you are trying to access the activity_main layout view (R.id.content_home) in your SettingsFragment. SettingsFragment should only call views from the layout it was inflated with in onCreateView()

Comment: im starting the fragment from another activity not the from the Main activity but the SettingsFragment is loaded on the main activity

Comment: thats the problem. you can't do that. you have to start the fragment from the activity it is loaded